# UWP How to deal with multiple selections

Tags: listview, uwp, multipleselection

I'm developing an application where I need to present some options from a service and capture the selection of some of these items from the user. In order to achieve that, I tried to use a ListView with SelectionMode="Multiple" but I've found some troubles with this approach.

[image: Application picture]

In the picture above, when the user select an item (from here I will call them "slots") from the left panel, the detail of the selected slot is shown in the right panel. My problem comes dealing with the "handling types" field. As you can see, a slot may have many handling types. I have the need to two-way bind the ListView's SelectedItems property to some property in my ViewModel but this is not possible (by the way, I'm following the MVVM pattern). There's a way to set the selected items from ViewModel and then capture any other selection (or deselection) that the user could made back to my ViewModel. Of course I would prefer a clean an easy solution but at this point any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Have you considered using the selectionChanged event of the listView? From the looks of it, it looks like a selectionChanged event task. If not, could you please elaborate or provide a demo sample app or something code or GIF or a YouTubeVid of what you're trying to achieve? It'll help us provide a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can not assign `Binding` into the read only property `SelectedItems` in UWP.

As a wrokaround, we can define the `IsSelected` property in the Class, the Class should inherit the INotifyPropertyChanged.

The class code:

```cs
public class Bundle : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private bool _isSelected;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

We can set false to the `IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled` that the `CheckBox` will not be shown. Then we can add a `CheckBox` control in the `DataTemplate`,  then we can bind the `IsChecked` property to the `IsSelected`.

For example:

```html
<ListView Name="MyListView" SelectionMode="Multiple"  IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled="False">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}"></CheckBox>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" ></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: This works pretty well, although with this approach it seems that SelectionMode and IsMultiSelectCheckBoxEnabled attributes are unnecessary